# Proper syntax for ListGetAt

Tags: list, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am getting a custom script error when trying to execute the following code. I might not have the proper syntax. I have googled `ListGetAt` examples and not able to find anything relevant. Thank you so much.

```
if(NOT isDefined(listGetAt(url.d,2,"/"))){
    writeOutput("You're not allow to access the directory.");
}
```

Comment: What the is the exact error and what is the value of url.d? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm not clear on the expected result either, but IsDefined() probably isn't the correct function to use here. It is designed to determine if the given variable *name* exists. Looks more like you're trying to test how many elements are in a list. If so, see [ListLen()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/listlen.html).

Comment: Also note that `listGetAt()` can throw an index out of bounds exception, for example if `url.d` doesn't contain any `/` char (list would only have 1 element, so accessing the 2nd element causes an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the length of the list. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here but here would be the equivalent code with a length check...

```
if(NOT listLen(url.d,"/") gte 2){
    writeOutput("You're not allow to access the directory.");
}
```

Comment: Hello Dan Roberts, This appears to be working. I'm going over my application to be sure. Will confirm with you shortly. Thanks for replying and sharing.

Comment: Just want to confirm that this did the job. Thank you very much, Dan! Thank you, everybody! Stay safe!

Answer (score -1):

```
<cfscript>
   url.d = "1/2";
   if(NOT isDefined(listGetAt(url.d,2,"/"))){
    writeOutput("You're not allow to access the directory.");
   }
</cfscript>
```

Hi Chung Lee,
  I think your url.d value have not second element in that list values. I've tried to reproduce that index error. I got the same index error. I've added an example code for your testing purpose. Please try it.
  Thanks.!